# ViewContainerRef with ResizeObserver doesn't work properly in angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to add and remove components dynamically depending on the the screen size using **ComponentFactoryResolver**.

```
@ViewChild('sidebarContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) sidebarContainer: ViewContainerRef;

_handleBodyResize() {
let self = this;
if (typeof ResizeObserver == 'undefined') return;

const obs = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  let entry = entries[0];

  if ((entry.contentRect.width) < MOBILE_WIDTH) {
    if (this.deviceType !== DeviceType.mobile) {
      this.removeSidebar();

      this.deviceType = DeviceType.mobile;
    }
  } else {
    if (this.deviceType !== DeviceType.desktop) {
      this.addSidebar();

      this.deviceType = DeviceType.desktop;
    }
  };
});

removeSidebar() {
  this.sidebarContainer.clear();
  this.sidebarRef.destroy();
}

addSidebar() {
this.sidebarContainer.clear();
//_cfr is componentFactoryResolver
const compFactory = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(this.array[0]);

let comp = this.sidebarContainer.createComponent(compFactory);

this.sidebarRef = comp;
}
```

**and the HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar-container">
<div #sidebarContainer>

</div>
```

This sidebarContainer viewContainerRef can't seem to hold on to the references and creates new instance of the SidebarComponent whenever the with of the body goes from `< 768px` to `>= 768px` and doesn't delete the previously created component saved in **sidebarRef** and event the **sidebarContainer.clear()** method doesn't work

Strangely if I use `window.addEventListener('resize'...` it works.

Is there some underlying **ResizeObserver** technicality that I am not aware of and is there a way to make it work with **ResizeObserver**

**Update**

I forgot to mention this, but the code inside the resize observer executes on time and calls both of the functions appropriately.

The else section always creates a new instance of the SidebarComponent and renders it into view but `this.sidebarContainer.clear()` and `this.sidebarRef.destroy` don't remove the previously created instances even though while debugging, I can see that `sidebarContainer` and `sidebarRef` are not undefined and are relevant instances of ViewContainerRef and ComponentRef respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular performs change detection in response to various triggers. DOM events, ajax requests, and timers/observables will trigger Angular's change detection.

The window's `resize` event is an example of a DOM event that will trigger change detection.

As far as I know, Angular's change detection is *not* automatically triggered by `ResizeObserver`. So you'll need to explicitly tell Angular to detect changes using [`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges):

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const obs = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    // Perform updates in response to resize

    // Then tell Angular to detect changes
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  });
  obs.observe(this.resizeDiv.nativeElement);
}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trzagi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

If you only care about changes to the viewport dimensions, there's no need to use `ResizeObserver`. The window `resize` event will work fine in all browsers.

Comment: It worked after `detectChanges()`, please see my update on the question and can you please explain why this happened as the relevant functions were called properly, just the sidebarContainer.clear() function didn't gave any error and didn't do its job

Answer (score 1):

`ResizeObserver` is not patched by `NgZone` like window DOM events. You can however explicitly run the `ResizeObserver` callback within `NgZone` like this:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const obs = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      // do what you got to do
    });
  });
  obs.observe(this.resizeDiv.nativeElement);
}
```

See [github issue](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1011)